# I am trying to get data stored in translation setting can I get without using schema class

Tags: translation

With out using the schema class is it possible to get the organisation data ,that is stored in translation settings

Answer (score 0):

The data stored in translation can be obtained using the metadata api. See the [Salesforce Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm#pickListValueTranslation) to see all the info that is accessible.